# Bash's "set -o vi" vs readline's own options?

Tags: bash, inputrc, vi-mode

I know there is, for readline,

```
set editing-mode vi
```

You can put the above option in `~/.inputrc`, [`editing-mode` is documented by Readline as](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline)

> `editing-mode` (emacs) Controls whether readline begins with a set of key bindings similar to `emacs` or `vi`. `editing-mode` can be set to either `emacs` or `vi`.

There is also, for Bash,

```
set -o vi
```

According to the [Bash documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

> `vi` Use a vi-style line editing interface. This also affects the editing interface used for read -e.

Does Bash's `-o vi` do *anything* other than set the appropriate Readline mode? And, if you've already got `editing-mode` set in your `~/.inputrc` does this do anything differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are identical.

Doing `set -o vi` in an interactive `bash` shell calls the `set` builtin.  [The C code for the `set` builtin calls `rl_variable_bind("editing-mode", option_name)`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/set.def?h=bash-4.4#n404) (where `option_name` will be `vi`) which is the Readline library function that sets the command line editing mode.

Setting the command line editing mode on the command line with `set -o` in the `bash` shell would override the corresponding setting configured in `~/.inputrc`.

Setting the editing mode in `~/.inputrc` would set it as the default command line editing mode for any application using the Readline library.